# SOQL query with Multi Select Picklist in where clause

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to build a query in Apex code to fetch all records where a multi select picklist has either of 2 values selected. When I build my query and string as option 1 it does not return back any data . However option 2 returns back corrent number of rows.

**option1**

```
    string str = '\'Ann-OP\',\'Ann-RP\'';

    List<Announcement__c> aL = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Announcement__c 
                                  WHERE Public_groups__c INCLUDES (:str) ];
```

**option2**

```
    List<Announcement__c> aL = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Announcement__c 
                                 WHERE Public_groups__c INCLUDES('Ann-OP', 'Ann-RP') ];
```

Comment: have you looked at https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008yY9IAI ?

Comment: Hadn't looked at that one. That way works. Why would query in option1 not work ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SOQL reads  `String str = '\'Ann-OP\',\'Ann-RP\'';` as a single Picklist value rather than two Picklist values `Ann-Op` and `Ann-RP`.

Try writing a dynamic SOQL query.

Example:

```
List<String> includesList = new List<String>{'\'Ann-OP\'','\'Ann-RP\''};
String queryString = 'SELECT Id, Name FROM Announcement__c  WHERE Public_groups__c INCLUDES(';
for(String includeValue :includesList)
    queryString += includeValue + ',';
queryString = queryString.removeEnd(',') +')';
List<Announcement__c> aL = (List<Announcement__c>)Database.query(queryString);
```

Comment: You could remove lines 3 - 5 and replace it with `+ String.join(includesList, ',') + ')';`. For completeness, you could also do a ternary condition to check if the list is null. Now, I may be mistaken but, I think you can also use a dynamic binding (`+ :includesList);` to replace lines 3-5) in the query string you built and that should also work.