# query for multipick list values

Tags: dynamic-soql

I want write down query to fetch value depend on Channel.
when user select Channel value is equal to Partner(pick list value) and then display value in dependent pick list for  Partner Level which have multi pick list values (Diamond , Gold).
how can write down correct query for same.
I have written below like :

```
String squery = 'SELECT Id, Channel__c,Partner_Level__c 
                 FROM MessageAlert__c 
                 WHERE Partner_Level__c 
                 INCLUDES (' + slist + ')';
```

Comment: have you linked your picklist (Channel) to the multipicklist (Partner Level) fields using dependent picklist option - https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_defining_field_dependencies.htm&language=en_US

Comment: yes. controlling field : channel

Comment: dependent field : Partner Level

Comment: are you trying to display these 2 fields in a visualforce page? then you don't need to run a query, you can use inputField to show both the fields and the values will change based on the mapping you defined between their values. here's a reference - https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_quick_start_dependent_picklists.htm

Comment: I want to fetch data based on both fields.

Comment: String squery = 'SELECT Id, Channel__c,Partner_Level__c 
                 FROM MessageAlert__c 
                 WHERE Partner_Level__c 
                 INCLUDES (:slist)'; Try this.
Other wise loop through the slist and create a comma seprated string and use that. Thanks

Comment: duplicate of http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46196/soql-query-with-multi-select-picklist-in-where-clause ?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to query MessageAlert records based on the picklist and multipicklist fields, then you can use a query like this

```
List<MessageAlert__c> = [SELECT Id,Name, Channel__c,Partner_Level__c 
                        FROM MessageAlert__c 
                        WHERE Channel__c = 'Partner' AND
                        Partner_Level__c INCLUDES ('Diamond , Gold')];
```

and if you want to build the query string dynamically, you can use something like

```
String queryStr = 'SELECT Id,Name, Channel__c,Partner_Level__c 
                   FROM MessageAlert__c 
                   WHERE Channel__c = \'' + YourPartnerPicklistValue + '\'' + 
                   'AND Partner_Level__c INCLUDES (\'' + 
                   YourPartnerLevelMultiPicklistValues +  '\')';
```

Note : replace **YourPartnerPicklistValue** and **YourPartnerLevelMultiPicklistValues** with your actual variables

Comment: Gettin g error .... unexpected token: ;

Comment: when user select Channel value is equal to Partner(pick list value) and then displayed value in dependent pick list for Partner Level which have multi pick list values (Diamond , Gold). now depend upon Partner Values , we want to show different different message for each so particular Partner level user can see own message alert , not others.  plz modify the below query . If possible can use string / boolean kind of concept.

Comment: **Depend upon Partner level, message will be filter out**

Comment: I have updated my answer based on your comments. let me know if that works or for any other changes

Comment: Getting error message.                MALFORMED_QUERY: unexpected token:

Comment: need to write down query like first check Partner level and depend on Partner Level , it will filter out Message for each Partner Level.
It will be kind of dynamic SOQL with comparison kind of each values of Partner level.

Comment: SELECT Id,Name, Channel__c,Partner_Level__c 
FROM MessageAlert__c 
WHERE Channel__c = 'Partner' AND
Partner_Level__c INCLUDES (:partnerLevel)

Comment: bind variables only allowed . error message getting.

Comment: were u able to get this working with the above query ?

Answer (score -1):

If you want to select records that have those values, you should use `IN` instead of `INCLUDE`.

```
String squery = 'SELECT Id, Channel__c,Partner_Level__c'+ 
             ' FROM MessageAlert__c'+
             ' WHERE Partner_Level__c IN :slist'+
             ' AND Channel__c = \'Partner\' ';
```

*Note the blank spaces at the beginning of each line.*

That'll select all Message Alerts with Channel `Partner` and Partner_Level__c in the `slist` (I'm considering that slist is a list of strings).

P.s.: make sure that each value on the `slist` is a string with no blank spaces or extra characters.