# Using In Clause with multi pick list

Tags: soql, api, query

I'm trying to query some data in access from a multi pick-list using this query:

```
SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact
WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c in ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker')
```

The problem is that it's only returning rows where the Summit_History is **just** "OOTS-2014-US-Speaker". Is there a way to do a fuzzy search, so that I'm returning rows that have this as at least one of the options, but not exclusively that option?

Comment: This answer might help http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/46196/soql-query-with-multi-select-picklist-in-where-clause

Comment: I tried previously to use INCLUDES, but am getting a "syntax error (missing operator)"message in Access

Comment: The only thing I could find similar was for contains vs includes but had the WHERE clause like this: WHERE INCLUDES(Contact.Summit_History__c, 'OOTS-2014-US-Speaker') haven't worked with access but figured it couldn't hurt to try.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use the INCLUDES

```
SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact
WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c INCLUDES ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker','myValue2','myValue3')
```

This will return any results that have at least one of the values in the INCLUDES filter.  if you need to filter for specific combinations, you'll ned to use this format

```
SELECT Contact.Account.Name, Contact.LastName, Contact.FirstName, Contact.Email, Contact.Title, Contact.Summit_History__c
FROM Contact
WHERE Contact.Summit_History__c INCLUDES ('OOTS-2014-US-Speaker','myValue2; myValue3')
```

This will yield any results that contain 'OOTS-2014-US-Speaker' OR ('myValue2' AND 'myValue3')

Comment: Is this valid?  I don't believe you can use the LIKE operator with multi selects.  Just one of many reasons I loathe them.....  Try running a test in apex anonymous, I don't believe this code works

Comment: @ChrisDuncombe, good catch!  I misread and saw Picklist, not Multi-Select Picklist.   This answer is entirely invalid.